# Gradle: Finding a shaded transitive dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Gradle project with many dependencies. We discovered a problematic dependency on "*dependencyZ*". "dependencyZ" was a transitive dependency and I had to find out where it was coming from.

It was a shaded dependency that was deeply nested coming from another transitive dependency!

I found this out manually but I would like to know if there is a command to generate the dependency tree that lists all the dependencies recusively?

I've already tried out many ways. Here are a few ways that didn't work.

Way 1:  `./gradlew -q subModule:dependencyInsight --dependency dependencyZ`

Way 2:  `./gradlew -q :subModule:dependencies`

Both these commands only go upto a certain level and don't go through all dependencies recursively.

Is there any other command or tool that can help?

I'm using Gradle 7 (Kotlin) with Gradle wrapper